# kubuntu Xenial i386 and 8GB of RAM

Tags: kubuntu, ram, pae

I'm running kubuntu 16.04 i386 and have just installed additional RAM. It seems that 16.04 doesn't have pae kernel:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-pae
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-generic-pae
```

However MemTotal sees my memory:

```
~$ grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8219532 kB
```

But KDE acts strange showing that I have 4 GB in System Information and a strange memory picture that makes me suspicious:

[image: screeshot]

So how can I find whether Ubuntu uses additional memory or not?

---

Upd: Okay, I've managed to enable PAE, but the picture is the same.

Upd2: I used the program `stress` to test the memory usage. As far as I understand, command

```
stress --vm-bytes 300M --vm-keep -m 20
```

creates 20 workers each consuming 300 Mb of RAM via constant maaloc/free. So I have consumed 300x20 = 6000 Mb. It has slowed my PC creating the following picture:
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzdzL.png)

Thus my 8 Gb in KDE are 4 Gb of RAM + 4 GB of swap. I tried to disable swap

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

The behaviour becomes weird, plasma crashes: [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c30hM.png)

I don't know what does it mean.

Upd3: So I installed 64-bit Ubuntu, everything is fine, here is a screenshot showing correct behaviour (click to enlarge): [image: kubuntu x64 8GB RAM]

Comment: A 32bit (i386) OS can't use that much RAM, 3-4GB max. If you want to use all that RAM you need the 64bit (X64) version.

Comment: @MarkKirby As far as I know, -pae (Physical Address Extension) kernel allows 32-bit OS access additional memory. But looks like Xenial doesn't have it.

Comment: Have you enabled it? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE?action=show&redirect=EnablingPAE Add it to grub on a full install.

Comment: @MarkKirby I have my system updated to 16.04 from 15.10 and I don't have Xenial CD. I've tried just now pressing 'e' in grub and adding "forcepae --forcepae" to the column of ubuntu boot options, it says "Unknown command" and then boots normally. My CPU supports PAE.

Comment: I can't find any up to date docs on pae, the older ones imply it should be installed by default. If you go to `advanced options for ubuntu` in grub, can you find it there?

Comment: @MarkKirby Looks like first time I did it wrong, now I've placed forcepae exactly after "splash" in kernel boot parameters [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters), loaded without error, but the situation is the same.

Comment: @MarkKirby  Looks like something works now! "dmesg | grep -i pae" changed from blank output to "PAE forced!"

Comment: @MarkKirby   `~$ dmesg | grep -i pae
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic root=UUID=9e69dd09-c3f8-4ac6-aeef-84690c9ed3b0 ro quiet splash forcepae -- forcepae intel_iommu=on iomem=relaxed vt.handoff=7
[    0.014097] PAE forced!
[    0.086669] PAE forced!
[    0.089530] PAE forced!
[    0.092028] PAE forced!`

Comment: @MarkKirby  KDE still says that I have 3,8 GB

Comment: Only way I can think to test it is open many applications and see if it stalls at 4gb. As a guide, I have Firefox open with10 tabs and that uses 1GB of RAM. You could open five of these with 10 tabs each and see if it crashes the system of not. There is a memory tester here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/memtester.8.html but I don't know if it will be much help to you.

Comment: @MarkKirby  I have updated my post. The results are weird, I think PAE may be working, but definitely not correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install Kubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-Bit.

Comment: Reinstalling entire system with all programs is a radical solution for me, maybe some workaround is still possible.

Comment: Yes it is a radical solution, but you don't have a choice. Install 64 bits architecture (RAM>=4Go) is the best way to let your PC better. :)