# Installing another Linux Distro

Tags: grub2, elementary

I had Elementary OS on my laptop and Windows 8 as a main system.EOS is not good enough for me, so i deleted it and I am with Win and Grub. Now I want to install Ubuntu, and don't know if should i removing Grub or just install Ubuntu and pray for overwriting. Will it overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu will reinstall Grub and it will automatically detect Windows loader on Windows partition. I've [just reinstalled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765036/kubuntu-xenial-i386-and-8gb-of-ram) my Ubuntu from 32-bit to 64-bit, having Win7 on another partition:

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048 1011320831 1011318784 482,2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *    1011320832 1231505407  220184576   105G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       1231505408 1241991167   10485760     5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda4       1242009598 1250263039    8253442     4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1242009600 1250263039    8253440     4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

You just need to select "Manual" while installing Ubuntu and make sure that "/" (Mount point) is set for your Linux partition and Windows partition is set to "not used". Grub should be installed on /dev/sda. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry. You can just go ahead with installing ubuntu. It will detect your windows and also install new grub if you choose to do so on MBR.
You can later create a rescue grub loader by installing the grub over a flash drive by doing so :

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb          [in my case]
```

you can use `fdisk -l` to find the flash drive letter.